# How to Read Azure KeyVault Secret in Asp.Net Core Web Api hosted on Azure VM IIS

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, azure-keyvault

The code below works on my local machine passing DefaultAzureCredential(). But when I host it on IIS on Azure VM, the authentication fails. I tried setting the ApplicationPool's identity to my credential since I have access to the Azure KeyVault, still the same 403 forbidden error. Deploying as AppServices on Azure is not an option currently.

What is the best way to read Azure KeyVault Secrets in this scenario?

```
string kvUri = "https://mykeyvault.vault.azure.net/";
string secretName = "MyConnectionString";

var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());
var secret = await client.GetSecretAsync(secretName);
Console.WriteLine(secret?.Value?.Value);
```

Comment: [This link](https://www.loginradius.com/blog/engineering/guest-post/using-azure-key-vault-with-an-azure-web-app-in-c-sharp/) may help, all code is [here](https://github.com/LoginRadius/engineering-blog-samples/pull/118).

Comment: Have you set up the managed identity on the VM?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to do it. Do I need to create App Registration for each of my app or Managed Identity or both on the azure portal? After creating Managed Identity how do I set it up on the VM?

Answer (score 1):

> still the same 403 forbidden error

We need to enable the system-assigned Managed Identity on the VM which we have deployed our Web App.

[image]

- And provide the permissions for the Identity which you have set in previous step.Run the below command in Azure CLI

```cs
az keyvault set-policy --name 'KeyVaultName' --object-id "ObjectID of SystemAssigned Managed Identity" --secret-permissions  get list set delete
```

Make sure you have given access permissions to retrieve the Key Vault.

In Azure Keyvault => Access policies , select the `Get,List` permissions and provide the `Principal` - name will be same as your deployed WebApp , continue with the steps and `Review +create`

[image]